# How to implement date field input

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

In my app page I have a filed to be filled for birthday (day and month) and I would like to provide a user with convinient way to do it.

Any advise?

Comment: `UIDatePicker` or `UIPickerView` or `UITextField` with `NSRegularExpression`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `UITextField` `inputView` property with a `UIDatePicker`